# Appending a char to a char*

Tags: c, string

I'm writing a program and I need to append a `char` to a `char*`.  I have a `char**` that represents lines of text.  I'm trying to take a single `char` at a time from `char**`, and add it to a `char*`.

So basically, I tried `strcat(char*, char[i][j])`, but `strcat` rejects `char[i][j]` since it's not a pointer.  I think I need to use `sprintf(char*, "%c", char[i][j])`, but I'm having trouble understanding how to append with `sprintf`.  I don't want it to overwrite what's already in my `char*`.

Any tips?

Comment: Is it really single characters you need to append or all lines?

Comment: I'm tokenizing the lines.  `char*` is a token.  I need to examine each `char` in the line and add it to my token, until I reach the beginning of a new token.

Comment: `strcat(char*, (char[]){char[i][j], '\0'});` if `char*` is enough space that you can add character.

Comment: Store the length of the destination string somewhere and just do somethin like `string[length - 1] = char[i][j]; string[length++] = '\0';`. Using `strcat()` is most of the time a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

You almost got it!

```
strncat (char *, & char[i][j], 1);
```

Calling `strncat` like that will copy exactly one `char` from your `char**` at position `[i][j]`. Just remember that it will also append the null character after that.

Comment: So if I append characters in a loop will I have a bunch of null characters?

Comment: No, just one at the end of your `char *`.

Comment: Thanks.  One last question, does my char* need to be initialized like char token[], or is char *token fine for this method?

Comment: This is completely unecessary. Do not do this.

Comment: Why not?  If I can keep the initialization as `char *token`, then this is perfect.  I'm tokenizing a potentially long line, and I'm not sure how long the tokens could be, so I'm trying to avoid creating a fixed sized array and messing with buffer overflow.

Comment: `strncat` works with both, but if you don't want to create a fixed size array then you have to use `char *`.

Comment: Yes it is. [http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strncat.html](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strncat.html)

Comment: @FernandoMoreira I see now.

Comment: So you think that searching the target string for the `null` terminator every time you want to add a single `char` to it is a good idea? Isn't it a better idea to store the length and capacity of the target buffer/array, check the current length and capacity of the target buffer/array, append a character manually using index notation, add the `null` terminator, increment the length and decrement the capacity a better solution?

Comment: When I try this in a test program with the second argument `&char[i][j]` gcc says it expects a `const char* __restrict__` but instead got a `char**`

Comment: @Pareod That's strange. Are your sure that your second argument is declared as `char**` or `*char[]` ?

Comment: @Pareod type of (you say "single char at a time from char**")`char[i][j]` is `char*`, not `char`. Show us your actual code.

Comment: @iharob I see your point and I would do that too. My point, beside giving a correct answer, was to show that Pareod almost got a valid solution.

Comment: And the situation is unknown. It is not necessarily the character insertion position is provided.

Answer (score 1):

given that you know that buf is defined as

```
char buf [MAXSIZE];
```

Let us assume that is has been initialized to an initial string and you want to add mychar to it (a single character)

```
i = strlen(buf);
if (i < MAXSIZE-1)
  {
    buf[i] = mychar; // Make the new character the last element of buf
    buf[i+1] = '\0' // end the new string with the null character
  }
```

This will append the new character and push the ending null character to ensure that it is a valid string. This is what strcat does when the appended entry is also a string or what strncat does when the count is 1. Note that the new strlen(buf) will now be i+1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `buf` is a 0 terminated c-string, you can use [`snprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
   size_t b_len;
   char buf[256];
   char ch = '!';

   strcpy(buf, "Hello world");
   b_len = strlen(buf); 
   snprintf(buf + b_len, sizeof buf - b_len, "%c", ch); 
   printf("%s", buf);

   char *p = malloc(256); /* check if malloc failed */
   strcpy(p, "Hello world");
   size_t len = strlen(p);
   snprintf(p + len, 256 - len, "%c", ch);
   printf("%s", p);

   return 0;
}
```

If `buf` happens to be pointer (such as an `malloc`ed pointer) then you can't use `sizeof` (it can only be used on an array to get the size).

Comment: So my I can't append to `*token`, it has to be `token[fixed_size]`?

Comment: @Pareod You can use append to a `char*` too. I have updated with another example.

Comment: If `buf` is a pointer to an array, then what is `buf + 1`?  Also, why is the second argument `sizeof buf -1`?

Comment: @Pareod That's not 1 but l :D I renamed it to make it clear.

Comment: Why in the world would you use `snprintf` for this instead of just `if (len  < 255) { p[len] = ch; }`?

Comment: @sfstewman It wasn't (and still) quite clear to me whether OP is just interested in appending just char or other stuff as well (such as int, etc).

Comment: Initially I was trying to add a character to a char array where it was initialized as such: `char *token = '\0'`.  My thinking was that I could add characters until I was done with a token, then set `token = '\0'` to reset it for the next token.

Comment: @Pareod `char *token = '\0';` is not even valid. You are assigning a char to a pointer. If it was `char *token = "\0";` or `char *token = "hello";` then you can't *append* to it as you are not allowed to modify the string literal. I am not quite sure what problem you are trying to solve. Can you update your question with a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

I have a very hard time understanding your question, instead of posting an example of what you want to achieve you explained something that seems to be based on your way of solving a problem with very little training and/or experience in the [c](/questions/tagged/c) language. So it's hard to write a good answer but definitely I will try to show you a way of doing something similar to what apparently you want to do.

The thing is, I highly doubt that `strcat()` is appropriate for this or for anything except, concatenating two strings. More than two, require something better than `strcat()`. And for a single `char` it's definitely less appropriate.

The following code appends all the characters in the string literal array into a single string, check it out

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char string[100];
    char lines[3][14] = {
       "First line...",
       "Another line.",
       "One more line"
    };
    size_t i;

    i = 0;
    for (size_t j = 0 ; ((j < sizeof(lines) / sizeof(lines[0])) && (i < sizeof(string) - 1)) ; ++j)
    {
        for (size_t k = 0 ; ((k < 13) && (i < sizeof(string) - 1)) ; ++k)
            string[i++] = lines[j][k];
    }
    string[i] = '\0';
    puts(string);

    return 0;
}
```